# How change image name according id field in php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, rename, image-uploading

i have register form include id,name,Lname,email,images in database.

### i want change image name that uesrs upload according id and then upload and insert into database with php.

user image name:324fg.jpg convert according id field name:12.jpg

12 is number of id user in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE userImage SET imageName='324fg.jpg' WHERE id=12";
```